# IVR on established call with UCMA

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

I want to place a call that I have in a conference, into an IVR sequence. What is the best approach for this? I'm thinking of two possibilities:

1. Take the call and place it into a new conference, where a UCMA created participant joins together with the call, to receive DTMF (ToneController) and play announces (Player).
2. Create a new AudioIVR object, which contains a Player, ToneController, AudioVideoCall and Conversation, connect this new object with B2BUA from my existing call to this AudioIVR, and run the sequence wihin this B2BUA.

It one (or both) or these approaches even possible??

Answer (score 0):

If your UCMA application registers for incoming audio calls, the cleanest thing to do would probably be to blind transfer the call to the SIP address of the UCMA application. Then you can deal with the IVR part when you answer the call, and don't have to worry about it being a conference (and don't have the 
server overhead of an un-needed conference).

As an added bonus, you also then have a UCMA application which can respond to incoming audio calls by putting them into a IVR sequence. You can hook this up to a phone number as well. Might be useful.

Looking at your two possibilities: I don't know if you can listen for DTMF calls on a conference call: I don't see why not, I've just not tried it. I don't think your second approach will work: when you back-to-back the calls need to be idle or establishing, not established.

Comment: The "problem" is that the call I want to attach an IVR on, is coming from a conference already. I know that you can collect DTMF in a conference, itt just require your app to have a participant with a ToneController object attached to this conference, no problem.
Regarding the second approach, one can easily turn a call from established into incoming state, by using "self-transfer" of that call.